# writing names(object) <- assignment method in R

Tags: r, oop, r-s4

I'm writing methods for an S4 class. I have written a "names" method as it follows:

```
setMethod("names","markovchain", 
       function(x) {
        out <- x@states
        return(out)
      }
)
```

thus returning the slot x@states composing the S4 markovchain object. Now I would like to add the names method the capability to set the x@states values. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a `names<-` method:

```
setMethod("names<-","markovchain", 
   function(x,value) {
    x@states<-value
    return(x)
   }
)
```